# Problem with the visibility of a variable in the included layout PHP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, scope

EDIT:
According to the question: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)
should work for me, but it does not. I probably don't understand something, but I can't see where the bug is.

I'm a newbie in PHP so the question is probably simple and stupid. I have 3 files: `index.php`, `View.php` and `layout.php`. In `View php` I have a View class definition and a `render()` method. Among others, this method includes an HTML template from the file `layout.php`.

But: in the PHP file in the `<main>` tag I have a piece of php code (`if` statement) which, depending on the value of the `$page` variable (defined in the PHP file), includes a different file

The problem is that this variable appears as undefined in the `layout.php` file.
I don't understand why, in the end all code is executed in `index.php`: View class is included and render function includes `layout.php`.

Please help me understand this, because I can't do it. Thanks in advance.

**Notice: Undefined variable: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\notes\templates\layout.php on line 17**

**index.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

require_once("src/utils/debug.php");
require_once("src/View.php");

$action = $_GET['action'] ?? null;

$view = new View();

$view -> render($action );
```

**View.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

class View
{
    public function render(?string $page): void
    {
        include_once("templates/layout.php");
    }
}
```

**layout.php**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Nagłówek</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php/?action=list">Lista notatek</li>
        <li><a href="index.php/?action=create">Nowa notatka</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <?php
    if ($page === 'create') {
    include_once("templates/pages/list.php");
    } else {
    include_once("templates/pages/create.php");
    }
     ?>

</main>
<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$action` is in the global scope, but functions and methods do not have global scope. You need to add the action as an argument to method `render`

Comment: I did it. From my index.php file:
$action = $_GET['action'] ?? null;

$view = new View();

$view -> render($action );

Comment: @whitelined Even if i add a line: $action = $page inside of render function, it sill dosent work

Comment: update your question to the new code, and I'll try and figure how to solve it.

Comment: Now that you've updated your code, assuming it's still not working, what does the error message say?